# Using ".htaccess" how do I hide parse errors for files in a specific folder?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, apache2

I need to hide parse errors for PHP files within a folder, but leave that one for all other PHP files. How would I do this?

Comment: This looks like an XY problem, please read: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: You should fix the parse errors, not try to hide them.

Comment: @MarcB Parse errors will still be handled (they're logged and that is checked). I just don't want them printing out to the browser.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen No, it is not. I want exactly what I asked for. Parse errors will still be handled (they're logged and that is checked). I just don't want them printing out to the browser

Comment: Why do you want to ignore them in the first place (XY)? And why do you want it differently based on a folder? This is really unusual. There is no reason you should be able to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all a good question and IMHO a valid one also.

Inside **.htaccess of the concerned folder where you want to hide PHP errors** put this line on top of the file:

```
php_flag display_errors off
```

This will affect only that folder and mask PHP errors for PHP files inside that folder while rest of the site will remain unaffected.

Comment: Thank you! I assume this still allows them to be logged, correct?

Comment: Yes logging will very much be there for this folder also (I had tested and verified before posting this answer).

Comment: One question (which might throw a wrench in this): is there any way to hide those errors only if a specific variable is not declared in those pages?

Comment: Hmm that makes thing more complex :P It is definitely possible with Apache 2.3+ but with older Apache versions I am not sure.